# Почему я не могу убрать предпросмотр ссылки в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'моя ссылка' , bot.disable_web_page_preview = True, reply_markup=keyboard1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "ru.stackoverflow.com/", disable_web_page_preview = True)
```